# VerificationException was unhandled : Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#, exception, verificationexception

I am trying to calculate normal map and bump map of some images. In order to do this, I am using [Craig's Utility Library](http://cul.codeplex.com/). However when I try to create bump map I am getting an exception saying

> "VerificationException was unhandled : Operation could destabilize the runtime".

How can I solve this? The code throws exception in second line (it throws the same exception for normal map too, but this one comes first):

```
        BumpMap bumpMap = new BumpMap();
        pic = bumpMap.Create(pic);
```

Answer (score 1):

That sort of of error usually happens when doing meta-programming (via something like `ILGenerator`), and getting it wrong; for example, issuing a "call" when a "callvirt" was needed, or borking the stack. It sounds to me like simply: a bug in the library. So report it to the author, or investigate it and fit it yourself.

It *is* technically also possible that the C# compiler has a bug and is emitting the wrong code, but that seems *relatively* unlikely.

Comment: I don't think it is because of a bug in the library. I want to search about meta-programming thing. Thank you.

Comment: @user1125953 why don't you think it is a bug in the library? a method call **doesn't work**: library bug! (my guess is that the library is using some meta-programming internally, and: has a bug; that's OK - it happens; the author just adds a unit test, fixes it, and carries on)

Comment: It may be of course. But I could't find anybody who experienced this error who are using this library. That's why I said so...

Comment: @user1125953 can you perhaps post the bits of the stacktrace that aren't specific to **your** code?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do that sorry

Comment: I think I found what you said :)
top 3 lines of stacktrace look like :
   
at Utilities.Media.Image.ExtensionMethods.BitmapExtensions.GetPixel(BitmapData Data, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 PixelSizeInBytes)
   at Utilities.Media.Image.Filter.ApplyFilter(Bitmap Input)
   at Utilities.Media.Image.BumpMap.Create(Bitmap Image)

Comment: it seems like it is not able to get pixels or what?

Comment: @user1125953 right; now we're getting somewhere. Do you know what the pixel size is? 32-bit RGBA? 24-bit RGB? anything else?

Comment: it says PixelFormat = Format32bppArgb

Comment: @user1125953 basically, the code checks for 24-bit, and assumes anything else is 32-bit; another approach might be to try it with a different image...

Comment: hmmm... the pointer-arithmetic *should* be OK for that; if you have the library side-by-side, you could debug GetPixel - looking in particular Scan0 has a value; I also wonder whether the BitmapData is being used outside the LockBits - this is **definitely** a library bug (although, it transpires, nothing to do with meta-programmig). I trongly suggest filing it as a bug with the author, along with a full repro